# C# Linq error msg "could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'double?'. 'Select' not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to set up a simple banking application that adds interest when the user makes a deposit. I have a textbox on the webform that accepts the deposit amount and when "Submit" is clicked the calculation will take place. however I get the "could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'double?'. 'Select' not found." message in my code. Balance is declared as a double? in the Accounts class. A lot of solutions I saw already were to add the using System.Linq namespace at the top but I've already done that.

```
public void GetInterest()
        {

            var db = new CelticSavingsBank.Classes.Accounts(); 

            var myBalance = from a in db.Balance
                             select a;
                db.Balance = myBalance + (myBalance * 0.03);    

        }

        protected void depositButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetInterest();
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your query is meant to be doing, however `db.Balance` is a `Nullable<double>` so you can't use linq to query over it.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  `from x in y select x` is not a magic incantation that reads a database.

Comment: See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/29/odd-query-expressions.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`db.Balance` is a `double?`.

Unless you have a very weird set of extension method, you can only run LINQ queries over a *collection*; namely, `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: *pedantry* `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: _super-pedantry_ `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: There are also built-in extension methods for LINQ support for `ParallelQuery<T>` (yes, which also implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but like `IQueryable<T>`, unless you have a very good reason, you shouldn't use the `Enumerable` extensions for it)